# How does C++ while code including two integers operate step by step?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am quite new to C++ programming, I have reviewed while loops in python before however the two integers confuse me here. I would be very happy if you can explain to me how this while loop operates step by step.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i;
    int j; 
    while(i<10 || j < 5) { // i kucuk ondan kucuk oldu surece {} icerisindeki islemler surekli olarak while() loopu ile tekrarlancak 
        cout<<"i: "<<i<<" "<<"j: "<<j<<endl;
        i = i + 1;  // eger bu kod olmaz ise, sonsuza dek i degerine basacak
        j = j + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not legal C++ as `i` & `j` are read before obtaining an initial value.

Comment: Provide an initial value for `i` and `j`, don't default construct them: `int i = 0; int j = 0;`. Fundamental types can be awkward like that.

Comment: One confusion, what do you want to achieve by using that loop? What's your desired output which you ain't getting?

Comment: What in particular do you find confusing? (Or would it be easier to answer: what behavior do you expect based on how you read this loop, and how does that differ from the actual behavior?)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was confused about the impact of the | | (or), I was confused about how the loop would have functioned step by step. Now I understand it, I also realized that I forgot to initialize the variables i and j, you are right on that one as well.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
/* You should first give a starting value
 to the I and j, otherwise they 
 will get a random number and your while won't work*/ 
    int i=0; 
    int j=0;
/* so as the word says "while" - while (something here is true)do the 
following code between the starting 
brackets and the finishing brackets. When it's not True skip the loop and go to the next line, in this example we will go to return 0 */ 

/*The value of i is 0 and the value of j is 0, and we first check if 0(i)<10 that's true next we check the other one 
if 0(j) < 5 yes do the following block*/
/* the || mean "or' if either one of them 
is true do the following block of code between the brackets*/

    while(i<10 || j < 5) {
        //we print
        cout<<"i: "<<i<<" "<<"j: "<<j<<endl;
        //we are incrementing the values of i and j for 1;
        i = i + 1;  
        j = j + 1;

        /*so what happens now it jumps again to the while
          and checks if the statement is true, now i = 1 and j = 1; 
          and this runs until i is 10 because only then the i won't be lesser then 
          10 and j won't be lesser then 5 it will be false*/ 
       */

    }
    //close the program
    return 0;
}
```

Hope I was clear!

Comment: Thank You for your response, I fully understand it now

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare variables in Python. A "variable" is created when you first assign a value to a name.  So you can't have uninitialized variables in Python.

That is not the case in C and C++. This code is declaring the `i` and `j` variables, but not assigning any values to them before trying to use them in the `while` loop.  So your code has *undefined behavior*, as the variables contain whatever *random* values happened to already be present in memory where they get allocated.

You need to initialize the variables before your loop tries to evaluate them:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I see my mistake now, I forgot to initialize the variables with integers. I understand now.